# Stacked Layout causing alignment to top problem

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a vertical layout with alignment set to "top" that contains what I want to be a fixed height "header" bar contained in a QHBoxLayout, with a QTextEdit window underneath it. One of the sections of this header bar contains a QStackedLayout. If you run the sample code below, when resizing the window the QTextEdit window begins pulling away from the "header" bar instead of staying anchored just underneath the "header" bar. The intended behavior would be for the QTextEdit window to remain anchored just underneath the header bar and expand and contract along its bottom margin. How do I fix the size of the QStackedLayout element to achieve this behavior?

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys

class Demo(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Demo, self).__init__(parent)

        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.main_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        # Header with combobox anchored to the top of the layout
        self.data_results_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.results_stacked_layout = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()
        self.data_results_layout.addLayout(self.results_stacked_layout)
        self.combobox_results_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.combobox_results_widget.setFixedHeight(25)
        self.combobox_results_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.combobox_results_widget)
        self.combobox_results_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.directory_combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.directory_combobox.setFixedHeight(25)
        self.combobox_results_layout.addWidget(self.directory_combobox)
        self.results_stacked_layout.addWidget(self.combobox_results_widget)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.data_results_layout)

        # QTextEdit Window
        self.asset_data_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.asset_data_window = QtWidgets.QTextEdit('Ready.')
        self.asset_data_layout.addWidget(self.asset_data_window)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.asset_data_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: change `self.main_layout.addLayout(self.asset_data_layout)` to `self.main_layout.addLayout(self.asset_data_layout, stretch=1)`

Comment: Thanks S. Nick- this option fixed the problem too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the alignment on a layout does *not* set the alignment of the widgets it manages, but only the alignment that *that layout* will have when added to *another* layout manager (you can read a more deeper explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64171542)).

Basically, the following:

```
layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
```

is almost the same as this:

```
otherLayout.addLayout(layout, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
```

So, not only that alignment won't affect the children alignment, but since you're using that layout as main layout for the widget, that alignment is completely ignored.

In order to achieve what you want you can set a stretch for the lower alignment (as suggested in the comment by S.Nick):

```
self.main_layout.addLayout(self.asset_data_layout, stretch=1)
```

On the other hand, consider that QStackedLayout should only used for custom widgets or dedicated behavior, and in most cases it's better to use its convenience class [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html), on which you can set an appropriate size policy:

```
    self.results_stacked_layout = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    self.data_results_layout.addWidget(self.results_stacked_layout)
    self.results_stacked_layout.setSizePolicy(
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
```

With the above, the stacked widget will resize itself horizontally according to its contents and will only use the minimum vertical space required by it: since the combobox expands horizontally as much as possible, it will try to occupy all the horizontal available space, and since the vertical policy of the combobox is fixed, it will only use the vertical space required, leaving all the remaining vertical space to the other widgets in the parent layout.

Note that the size policy definitions might seem a bit counterintuitive; the rule is that it's always referred to the sizeHint of the widget: `Maximum` means that the size hint of the contents will be used as *maximum size*, and it cannot be larger than that.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to explain this to me. I've ran into this scenario before and at the time opted for an entirely different layout just to get around it.